# Converting globals to class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been using global variables for a little text game in python and have come across a lot of articles saying that global variables are a no no in python. I have been trying to understand how to get what I have below (just a health variable and being able to change it and print it) working using classes but I am confused how I can converted something like this in a class. Any help, example, point in the right direction would be great.

Here is an example of me using variables.

```
import sys
import time

health = 100
b = 1

def intro():
    print("You will die after two moves")


def exittro():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    sys.exit()


def move():
    global health
    global b
    health -= 50

    if health <= 51 and b >0:
        print("almost dead")
        b = b - 1


def death():
    if health == 0 or health <= 0:
        print("...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You died\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Dont worry, this game sucks anyway\n")
        exittro()

intro()

a = 1

while a == 1:
    input("Press Enter to move")
    move()
    death()
```

Thank you

Edit: this is the kind of thing I have been trying to do...

```
class Test:
def __init__(self):
    number = 100

def __call__(self):
    return number

def reduceNum(self):
    number -=10

def printNum(self):
    print(number)

a = 1
while a == 1:
    input("Enter")
    Test.self.reduceNum()
    Test.self.printNum()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting an error? Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Something like this, many adapted variations of it `class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        number = 100

    def __call__(self):
        return number

    def reduceNum(self):
        number -=10

    def printNum(self):
        print(number)

a = 1
while a == 1:
    input("Enter")
    Test.self.reduceNum()
    Test.self.printNum()`

Comment: Anthony, add the code to the original question.

Comment: Have a class for the player and class variables (e.g. `self.whatever`) for the player's stats maybe? Honestly, if your code isn't going to be too much more complex than your example, then globals are fine. Also methods for those functions

Comment: If you aren't familiar with classes, you could always read up on them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid classes for this, as classes are generally slower. You could make the function return the new value for the `health` variable.

I would also suggest making a main controller function to take the return value and apply it to other functions. This prevents global variables outside of a function's scope.

```
import time

def intro():
    print("You will die after two moves")


def outro():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    # sys.exit() # You can avoid this now by just stopping the program normally


def move(health):
    health -= 50

    if health <= 51:
        print("almost dead")
    return health  # Return the new health to be stored in a variable


def death(health):
    if health <= 0:
        print("...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You died\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Dont worry, this game sucks anyway\n")
        return True  # Died
    return False  # Didn't die

def main():
    health = 100  # You start with 100 health
    intro()
    while not death(health):
        # While the death function doesn't return `True` (i.e., you didn't die) ...
        input("Press enter to move")
        health = move(health)  # `health` is the new health value
    outro()
```

If you want to use classes, you need to actually instantiate the class (Make a new object from it) by doing `instance = Test()`. You also need to store variables as attributes of self (so `self.number = number`) as any local variables are different from each other.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 100

    def __call__(self):
        return self.number

    def reduceNum(self):
        self.number -= 10

    def printNum(self):
        print(self.number)

a = 1
game = Test()
while a == 1:
    input("Enter")
    game.reduceNum()
    game.printNum()
    # Or:
    print(game())
    # As you've changed `__call__` to return the number as well.
```

Comment: Great thank you that is what I was after, much appreciated

Comment: Why are classes generally slower?

Comment: @nycynik Python built-ins, like `dict`s and `set`s are implemented natively (So for the regular Python that you download from python.org, in C), and have a ton of optimizations. Classes can't have nearly as many optimizations, as they can be anything so Python can't speed them up

Comment: @Artyer: That a mostly nonsense explanation. The non-C parts of classes are regular Python functions, just like in your non-class case. Class instances themselves are implemented in terms of `dict`s, and benefit from the optimizations of `dict`s (many of which were made *specifically* to support the class and class instance cases). Access instance attributes *is* typically a little slower than access globals (to support the descriptor protocol, it requires at least two `dict` lookups when `__slots__` aren't involved; accessing globals only involves one), but the loss is typically minimal.